# How to change url path with puppeteer after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, puppeteer

I'm trying to change the URL path because I have path variable I use, I don't want to do it with page.click because I reach a dead end at some point.

My code is:

```
const generarPDF = async (id, fecha) => {
    const usuarios = await Usuarios.find();
    usuarios.forEach(async dato => {
        const urlBase = 'http://localhost:3000';
        const urlDestino = '/monitor/604c058e90de8c58c8c5ddb3';
        const navegador = await puppeteer.launch();
        const pagina = await navegador.newPage();
        await pagina.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
        await pagina.goto(urlBase);
        await pagina.type('#usuario', dato.usuario);
        await pagina.type('#passwd', '1234');
        await pagina.click('#ingresar');
        await pagina.goto(urlBase+urlDestino)
        await pagina.pdf({ path: 'archivos/incidencia1.pdf', format: 'A4' });
    })
}
generarPDF();
```

These three lines are the ones I use to log in

```
await pagina.type('#usuario', dato.usuario);
await pagina.type('#passwd', '1234');
await pagina.click('#ingresar');
```

I know I login correctly, the problem is when I do the second page.goto because it logs me out, Is there any way to prevent that from happening. If I put the url manually it works, also if I do page.url() I obtain the correct url, so the problem is that it logs me out.

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 0):

When you use .goto(...) puppeeter wait for the page loading.

When you use .click(...) , NOT. ( https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pageclickselector-options )

probably you change page before the login page endpoint is fully loaded. Try replace:

```
await pagina.click('#ingresar')
```

with

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  await pagina.click('#ingresar'),
  page.waitForNavigation({'waitUntil':'networkidle0')
]);
```

Ps... usually i prefer, instead of waitForNavigation, waitForSelector. For example, if in the "login confirmation page" there is a div like: `<div class="login-conf">`

You can write:

```
await pagina.click('#ingresar');
await waitForSelector('div.login-conf', 'timeout':3000)
// raise an exception if after 3seconds the page is not loaded with this element
```

Comment: Replacing the code you sent, gives me timeout of 30000ms exceeded, I onyl wrapped the await pagina.click('#ingresar'), pagina.waitForNavigation() like you said and  left tha last two lines outside f it

Comment: Networkidle0 requires the website fully load (no request of and kind). You can try networkidle2, that Is a bit less restrictive. Much vetter using waitForSelector: identify a selector in the "login confirm" page allow you tu know of the script really do the login

Comment: What is login confirm, is it a selector before or after the login is done?

Comment: After, when the login is successfully.
The page wait until the selector of the "welcome page" load. If dont load untile 30 s, (u can customize with {maxwait: x} ... raise an exception ,meaning that the login does not work (maybe wrong password, or other...)